# О наследовании в С++

Tags: c++, наследование

Задание от преподавателя ООП в вузе. 
Вычислить сумму чисел наследуемых классов используя методы доступа. И такая схема.
[image: Схема]
Как я понимаю, наследуется структура класса, а не значения переменных в его объектах и т.д.
Это вообще возможно?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B1 {
  int a;
};

class B2 {
  int b;
};

class D1 : protected B1 {
  int c;
};

class D2 : public B1 {
  int d;
};

class D3 : protected D2, protected B2 {
  int e;
};

class D4 : public D1, public D3{
  int f;
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"наследуется структура класса, а не значения переменных в его объектах"* Не понял вопрос. Может кодом продемонстрируете?

Comment: К примеру в `D3` есть функция
`add() {
cout<<a+b+d+e;
}`
В `int main()`
Создаем объекты
`B1 b1(4); D2 d2(8); B2 b2(2); D3 d3(1); //предположим там еще и конструктор есть`
И мы вызываем функцию суммирования
`d3.add(); `
Но у нас в `d3` у переменных `a, b, d` нет значений чтобы суммировать.

Comment: Да, все так. Суть наследования в том, что внутри объектов дочерних классов находятся (под)объекты родителей. Все эти подобъекты внутри `d3` никак не связаны с `b1`, `d2`, `b2`, `d3` в `main`.

Comment: Что должна задавать ваша диаграмма? Иерархию классов? Или иерархию подобъектов? В той иерархии, что вы реализовали, каждый объект `D4` содержит **два** разных подобъекта `B1`. Это то, что вам надо или не то? На диаграмме `B1` указан только один раз. Означает ли это, что подобъект типа `B1` должен быть только **один**? Без четкого ответа на этот вопрос задача не ясна и пытаться решать ее бессмысленно.

Answer (score 3):

Может как-то так?

```
class A {
    int a;

public:

    A(int val) : a(val) {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual int getSum() {
        return a;
    }
};

class B {
    int b;

public:

    B(int val) : b(val) {}
    virtual ~B() {}

    virtual int getSum() {
        return b;
    }
};

class C : protected A, public B {
    int c;

public:

    C(int val1, int val2, int val3) : A(val1), B(val2), c(val3) {}

    virtual int getSum() override {
        return A::getSum() + B::getSum() + c;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << C(1, 2, 3).getSum() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> А когда А и Б унаследованны от одного базового класса? у вас наверное
>   2 раза вернется от него значение? а если будет еще С унаследованный от
>   него же ? будет уже 3, можно конечно, статическое поле с флагом
>   возврата пришить, но это такое....

Хороший вопрос! Это так называемое diamond наследование. Для данного случая в C++ существует виртуальное наследование. С ним в классе `C` не будет дублирование полей `Base` из классов `A` и `B`, но придётся инициализировать поле `Base` класса уже в классе `C`, ну и переиспользовать `getSum` из родительских классов уже не получится (по крайней мере я не очень представляю как это можно сделать)

```
class Base {
protected:
    int base;

public:

    Base(int val) : base(val) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual int getSum() {
        return base;
    }
};

class A : virtual protected Base {
protected:
    int a;

public:

    A(int val) :Base(500), a(val) {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual int getSum() override {
        return a + base;
    }
};

class B : virtual protected Base {
protected:
    int b;

public:

    B(int val) : Base(1000), b(val) {}
    virtual ~B() {}

    virtual int getSum() override {
        return b + base;
    }
};

class C : protected A, protected B {
protected:
    int c;

public:

    C(int val1, int val2, int val3) : Base(100), A(val1), B(val2), c(val3) {}

    virtual int getSum() override {
        return base + a + b + c;
    }
};

int main() {

    cout << C(1, 2, 3).getSum() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Модификаторы при наследовании забыли.

Comment: @Drawn Raccon А когда А и Б унаследованны от одного базового класса? у вас наверное 2 раза вернется от него значение? а если будет еще С унаследованный от него же ? будет уже 3, можно конечно, статическое поле с флагом возврата пришить, но это такое....

Comment: @Beeen007 обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Странно, но это работает. Пришлось использовать виртуальное наследование.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B1 {
  public:
  int b1;
  B1() {
    b1=4;
  }
};

class B2 {
  public:
  int b2;
  B2() {
    b2=6;
  }
};

class D1 : virtual protected B1 {
  public:
  int d1;
  D1() {
    d1=3;
  }
};

class D2 : virtual public B1 {
  public:
  int d2;
  D2() {
    d2=1;
  }
};

class D3 : protected D2, protected B2 {
  public:
  int d3;
  D3() {
    d3=6;
  }
};

class D4 : public D1, public D3{
  public:
  int d4;
  D4() {
    d4=5;
  }
  void add() {
    cout<<"Suma: "<<b1+b2+d1+d2+d3+d4<<endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  B1 b1;
  B2 b2;
  D1 d1;
  D2 d2;
  D3 d3;
  D4 d4;
  d4.add(); //Outputs 25
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `D4().add();` в `main` достаточно. Без всяких других объектов

Comment: Что же тут странного? Странно, что вы не начали с того, чтобы разобраться с сутью задания.